# add text to imageview inside horizontalscrollview in android programming

Tags: android

I want to add a text below to each of the ImageView Inside the  horizontal scroll view .

I tried using relative layout and also linear layout .

Is there a better way to do it?

### and my activity xml will look like

```
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/image1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5px"
            />

        <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="text1"
    android:textSize="20px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image1"
    />
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/image2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5px"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image1"/>
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/image3"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/image3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5px"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image2"/>
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/image4"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/image4"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5px"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image3"/>

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/image5"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/image2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5px"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image4"/>

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/image6"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/image3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5px"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image5"/>
    </RelativeLayout>





 </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding Linear Layout with orientation vertical  as a child to outer Linear Layout whose orientation is Horizontal. Add image and textview to inner linear layout so that both of them will be vertical

Updated activiyt xml

---

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/latestOffers"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10px"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image1"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                    android:src="@drawable/image1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text1"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:text="text1"
                    android:textSize="20px" />
            </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're referring to another id to set the alignment, don't use `@+id`. Just use `@id`. Using the plus means you want to create a *new* id with that name. It's probably getting confused, since that causes duplicate ids within your layout.

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:layout_below="@id/image1"
/>
```

I notice you do the same with the following ImageViews, so go through and fix those also.

Comment: I am getting the same issue , my text and image are misaligned and I am not able to see the other images apart from the first one .

Comment: It might help to update the xml in your post to reflect it, and a screenshot would help a lot as well.